# Monit - Check if process exists and kill when consuming X memory

Tags: monit

I have 'someprocess' running on some hosts, and want a single monit check for hosts with and without 'someprocess' running, which kills someprocess when memory usage exceeds a threshold.

Below check works, but on hosts not running someprocess monit continually logs "process is not running" in /var/log/monit.log.

```
check process someprocess
    matching "someprocess"
    if memory usage > 2% for 1 cycle then exec "/usr/bin/kill someprocess"
```

I want to also include 'if exists' but keep getting monit systax errors, Im not sure I can have more than one if statement.

Does anyone know if I can do this, so have something along the lines of:

```
if exists AND memory usage > 2% for 1 cycle then exec "/usr/bin/kill someprocess"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an additional test and disable the monitoring if the application is not available, to prevent floating the logs with messages.

```
check process someprocess matching "someprocess"
  if memory usage > 2% for 1 cycle then exec "/usr/bin/kill someprocess"
  if not exist for 5 cycles then unmonitor
```

This will disable the check, if the application is not available for 5 monitor cycles. To enable the monitoring again, use "monit monitor someprocess".

See https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#EXISTENCE-TESTS